# How to set metadata with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, metadata, edit

JavaFX has a method to read the metadata of a media file but where is the method to change them?

```
media.getMetadata()
```

but no

```
media.setMetadata()
```

??

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do, but `getMetadata()` returns a map... It doesn't say it's unmodifiable, so why don't you try `media.getMetadata().put(key, value);`??

Comment: Throws an "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)"

Comment: OK, so then the map is unmodifiable. What are you intending to do, anyway? The metadata is part of the file (or other resource, wherever you get the media from). There is no API to write to the file anyway, so it doesn't really make sense to change the metadata.

Comment: "There is no API to write to the file anyway" <- that is the question of this thread, there is a getter API to read out of a file but I can't find a setter API to write metadata into a file.

Comment: "My point is there is no API to save the file " <- that's the question of this thread, a simple "No, there is no API" would have been sufficient instead of ignoring the question. And I don't care about streaming media, if there is a getter for data also expecting a setter makes sense. You can load a textfiled, change content and save it on disk without hassle in Java so I don't see how my question shouldn't make sense.

Comment: "if there is a getter for data also expecting a setter makes sense". No. Read, e.g. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072958/immutable-java-objects.html

Comment: A simple Media mediaFile =  new Media ("path/to/mp3"); mediaFile.setMetadata("artist", "abcd"); mediaFile.writeOnDisk(); for example.

Comment: The media is [loaded from a URI, specified as a string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html), and the metadata property represents the metadata loaded from that URI. If you could change the metadata, it would no longer represent the metadata loaded from the URI, and the `Media` object would be inconsistent. There is no way in general you can overwrite the content of a URI.

Comment: Please take care to ask the question you mean. In your comments you claim the question you posted is "is there an API to save the file [sic]". If you read the question, you clearly don't ask anything about saving the "file".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No API available to set Metadata via JavaFX.